# Kayle as a support or solo top?

Tags: league-of-legends

So I've played League of Legends since season 1, and after the season ended, we got our Kayle+skin. Ever since than, I haven't seen her being played by anyone. Is there a reason behind that? I think she is a pretty good support and can be a great dps!

Comment: Welcome to Gaming Stack Exchange, Plussmaci! As your question stand now, it invites discussion rather than a definitive answer. Stack Exchange's network of sites are a Q&A site that specializes in question that can be answered with one answer rather than a back and forth discussion. A way you can edit the question to make it more constructive is to ask what type of role she can optimally fill or what items she can utilized the best based on her skillset.

Comment: Thank you, kind of what i wanted to ask, but i got carried away :)

Comment: Also, please limit yourself to one question at a time. I removed the 2nd paragraph as it was essentially a different question. Also, it's a bit unclear what you are asking here - are you wondering which role that champion should take, or are you wondering why is it relatively unused?

Answer (score 1):

You should go top. She can lash out tons of damage but she can't really do much in support roles. Her healing is weak (unlike other champions like sona, soraka, alistar) and she's got weak CC (unlike, janna and alistar) so do not play her support, but top lane, where she can play counter :)

Answer (score 1):

Kayle is actually a very decent carry. When her Reckoning is maxed out, attacking a slowed enemy will do 10% more damage! Combined with her ultimate that makes her invincible for an amount of time, she can be very hard to shut down.

Often many players underestimate her due to the fact that she is not played often and is usually thought of as a support.

I suggest you look up some builds on AD Kayle on sites such as MOBAFire and Solomid, and see if you're successful.

Comment: I think that most people remember Kayle from before her revamp and haven't tried her since then. Now as you say Kayle is a decent carry with tons of utility.

Comment: Thank you. So many people argue with me about Kayle, even in High ELO :/

Answer (score -1):

As you can see in this video of the next patch preview:

"Kayle is a hybrid carry and support champion, but just isn't strong enough to fill either of this role"

---

This was the patch that changed Kayle: [V1.0.0.120](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/V1.0.0.120#Hotfix)

> - **Holy Fervor:**
>
>   - Attack damage to ability power conversion ratio reduced to 20% from 30%.
>   - Ability power to attack damage conversion ratio reduced to 10% from 15%.

---

> - **Reckoning:**
>
>   - Base damage increased to 80/130/180/230/280 from 60/110/160/210/260.
>   - Ability power ratio increased to 1.0 from 0.8. Mana cost reduced to 70/75/80/85/90 from 80/85/90/95/100.

---

> - **Divine Blessing:**
>
>   - Heal changed to 60/115/170/225/280 from 65/100/135/170/205. Ability power ratio reduced to 0.25 from 0.5. Movement speed boost increased from 12% at all ranks to 18/21/24/27/30%.
>   - Duration reduced to 4 seconds from 10. Mana cost increased to 75/90/105/120/135 from 60/65/70/75/80.

---

> - **Righteous Fury:**
>
>   - Base bonus damage increased to 10/20/30/40/50 from 4/10/16/22/28.
>   - Range buff increased to 425 from 400. Cooldown reduced to 17 at all ranks from 22/21/20/19/18. Mana cost reduced to 50 from 65.

Comment: Kayle is one of the best top heroes and built as a pure AD carry her damage is just insane. If you calculate her utility (Divine Blessing, Ultimate) into the equotation it gets even better.

Comment: Sorry, but why did I got down-voted?

Answer (score -2):

She can be played in every single capacity except maybe ad carry. I've seen her go support which is fine since her early game damage and harrass is pretty good.

She can also be played mid, top, or jungle in which case most people build her as an attack speed on-hit effect champion.

Comment: Kayle is best AS AN AD CARRY! Hybrid/support Kayle is just weak. On hit kayle is just retarded. Don't answer a question about a hero you clearly never played.